# CALPUFF dispersion model - orography

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, software

Is it possible to use [CALPUFF](http://www.src.com/) in ISC-type single-station mode accounting for "simple" terrain effect (like in ISC)?

Can I set the orography out of [CALMET](https://www.enviroware.com/calmet/)?